# Regex/Javascript; negatively select a repeat of two characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Perhaps this question, or one that required a similar answer, has already been asked but I couldn't find it. If so link to it and this one can be removed.

I'm okay with regex, whenever I can use it (and it makes sense to) I do, but I am at a loss with this seemingly simple problem. 
I'm searching through a minified css file with parts looking like the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1234px){.some{thing:else;}.more{text:stuff;}}
```

I'm looking to "capture" the style rules inside the media queries.
The regex I have is the following:

```
/@media[^\{]+\{([^\}]+\})/
```

Which will select for ".some{thing:else;}" but it will stop once it reaches the first "}".
What I want to select for in the regex is NOT the two }} characters. So select everything untill you reach two }} charaters. You could select for them like this `[\}]{2}` but how do you negatively select for two of the same characters together?

Some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just repeat the capturing group:

`@media[^\{]+\{((?:[^\}]+\})+)`

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lK5zY0/1).

Comment: Somehow I find this solution more readable but I guess the other one is more general. I didn't know you could repeat a group...dono why I thought that...ty

Comment: Having tried both options more extensively (was busy), I noticed that the other answer doesn't do what I would like it to do, the `.+` option selects as much as it can (what is the official term "greedy"?) and and I want the opposite the `[^\}]+` option does what I want and no more.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media[^{]*{((?:.*?{.*?})*)}
```

See the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xO3kW9/2)

Comment: I guess this is the solution I'm looking for, although I'm not interested in hits if they are empty that's why I used `+` in stead of `*`. ty

Comment: Like i said in the comment on the other answer the addition of the second `.+` in the `(?:.*?{.*?})*` part causes the regex to select all but everything, it's to "greedy".